# Syncfusion grid filteration in angular

Tags: angular, syncfusion

how to disable autocomplete while filtering in Syncfusion Grid
[image]

I've tried this:

```
actionBegin(args) {
    if (args.requestType === 'filtering' && args.currentFilterObject.value == null) {
      const filterPopup = document.getElementsByClassName('e-filter-popup')[0];
      const autoCompleteInput = filterPopup.querySelector('.e-autocomplete') as HTMLInputElement;
  
      // Check if the autoCompleteInput is available
      if (autoCompleteInput) {
        const filterValue = autoCompleteInput.value;
  
        // Set the filter value for the current filter object
        args.currentFilterObject.value = filterValue;
  
        // Set the filter value for the column in the arguments
        args.columns.forEach((column) => {
          if (column.field === args.currentFilteringColumn) {
            column.value = filterValue;
            console.log(column);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
created() {
    (this.grid as any).on('beforeCustomFilterOpen', () => {
      (
        this.grid as any
      ).filterModule.filterModule.excelFilterBase.dlgObj.element
        .querySelectorAll('.e-autocomplete')
        .forEach((input: any) => {
          (
            input.parentElement.querySelector('.e-clear-icon') as HTMLElement
          ).classList.add('e-clear-icon-hide');
          input.ej2_instances[0].autofill = false;
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add details as explaination of what you changed and why this should answer the question

Answer (score 0):

To disable AutoComplete, you can use the **beforeCustomFilterOpen** internal event. Set the **autofill** property to **false** for the AutoComplete control to prevent auto complete action in the Custom Filter. Additionally, you can employ CSS to hide the suggestion dropdown. Please refer to the code snippets and sample below:

```
[app.component.css]

  .e-ddl.e-popup.e-popup-flmenu.e-lib.e-control.e-popup-open {
        display: none;
   }


[app.component.ts]

 created() {
    (this.grid as any).on('beforeCustomFilterOpen', () => {
      (
        this.grid as any
      ).filterModule.filterModule.excelFilterBase.dlgObj.element
        .querySelectorAll('.e-autocomplete')
        .forEach((input: any) => {
          (
            input.parentElement.querySelector('.e-clear-icon') as HTMLElement
          ).classList.add('e-clear-icon-hide');
          input.ej2_instances[0].autofill = false;
        });
    });
  }
```

Sample: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grid-filter-disable-autofill](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grid-filter-disable-autofill?file=src%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp.component.ts)